# How to setup squid simplest way for safe proxy?

Tags: configuration, squid, http-proxy

I have installed `squid` on my remote linux box and added my desktop's IP as

```
acl lagrangian64 src XX.XX.XX.XX/32
```

in squid config.

Also I have added `lagrangian64` to the following line:

```
http_access allow manager localhost lagrangian64
```

Was this enough and correct?

I am getting and error while browsing any site with this proxy:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.google.com/
...
Access Denied
...
```

How to allow myself to browse? What I did up for now?

Answer (score 1):

The line `http_access allow manager localhost lagrangian64` allows you to access squid's management interface. All conditions must be matched for a rule to apply - in this case, your IP and localhost (which is impossible) must try to access the manager (which is defined in an earlier `acl manager` line in the default config file). This should work:

```
# Allow your IP to everything HTTP
http_access allow lagrangian64
# Allow localhost access
http_access allow localhost
# Deny all other access
http_access deny all
```

You might also want to comment out some other deny lines, like one limiting the SSL ports.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring settings in `squid.conf` have you reload squid configuration by doing `squid -k reconfigure` ?  or have you restart squid service ? if possible post your all params in squid.conf `grep -Ev "^$|^#" /etc/squid/squid.conf`